# Patton Copula model code and significance of parameters

Tags: copula, dependence

I am trying to implement a copula model using the Patton (2006) Matlab code.  I am unable to determine the significance of the parameters. Does anyone know how i can generate the standard errors from the code. Similarly, if there is an alternative R copula code please assist. Thank you.

Comment: For copula's, I've generally just used some sort of argsort transform (or see pandas rank) to do some empirical embedding of the data

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy-without-sorting-array-twice/

then you can do whatever you want in either uniform or gaussian space. Not sure what Patton is doing.